# CSS element does not work in Chrome when printing

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing

The following CSS works in all browsers except Chrome when printing:

```
.example {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  text-align: right
}
```

I am not interested in what is displayed in the browser, only what is printed.

Is this a bug? Is there a workaround?

**EDIT: This seems to be a problem with Chrome's built-in PDF plugin.**

Comment: How does it not work? Not printed at all, printed in the wrong position, printed on the wrong page...

Comment: Does not print at all. (It used to work in Chrome - but lately their print and "print preview" - they do not call it that - has changed).

Comment: please add code that shows how the above css is included (examples: see my answer)

Answer (score 2):

your css is included in the html with something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css" media="screen" />
```

either delete the media="screen", or add another for printing:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print"/>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_media.asp

Comment: The OP said it worked in all other browsers, so I doubt that's it.